# I have a constructor that stores values into a double[][] instance variable. I would like to use double array as a variable in my main function

Tags: java, arrays

I have a constructor that takes in the number of rows/columns and file location of a txt file and stores those values into a `String` array.

```
int rows;
int columns;
int count;
File fileLocation;
String[][] stringArray;
Double[][] doubleArray; // Used in my convertToDoubleArray() method

public StoreArray(int rowsI, int columnsI, File fileLocationI){

        int i;
        int j;

        InputStream fileInputStream;
        BufferedReader bufferedReader;
        String line;

        rows = rowsI;
        columns = columnsI;
        count = 0;
        fileLocation = fileLocationI;
        stringArray = new String[rows][columns];

        try{
            fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(fileLocation);
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));

            for(i = 0; i < rows; i++){ // iterate through row
                for(j = 0; j < columns; j++){ // iterate through column
                    while((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null){ // while the next line is not null
                        stringArray[i][j] = line; // assign i-th j-th index as line (RGB value)
                        count++;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The purpose of this is because I am using a Java library called JHeatChart which takes in `double` arrays and displays the array-containing values as a heat chart.

So the main function that I use is:

```
File timeValuePath = new File(filePath);
int timeValueRow = 93;
int timeValueColumn = 14;

StoreArray timeValueArray = new StoreArray(timeValueRow,timeValueColumn,timeValuePath);
timeValueArray.convertToDoubleArray();
```

`convertToDoubleArray()` is a method I wrote that simply takes each String input (since `BufferedReader` only allows String parameters) and converts it to double. It also returns an error when the input isn't a Double.

Since the input for `JHeatChart` is a `double[][]`, and my constructor indeed stores values into a `double[][]` instance, how do I "use" the `timeValueArray` object as a double array? I apologize if I am not using the terminology correctly. Thank you.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "use"? Do you mean, for example, you'd like it to behave at times like a 2d double array, such as `timeValueArray[1][4]`? If so, I would simply make a method (call it "get" for example) which accepts two index parameters (ex: `get(int rowIndex, int columnIndex)`. Am I off?

Comment: Essentially what I mean is - in my main function I would like to use `timeValueArray` as an array object, so, for example, I can use `timeValueArray[][]` as an input (which is a double array) to JHeatChart's constructor.

Comment: Actually, I think I can create a method that /returns/ a double array instead. Let me get back to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public Double[][] convertToDoubleArray(){
    int i;
    int j;
    doubleArray = new Double[rows][columns];

    for(i = 0; i < rows; i++){ // iterate through row
        for(j = 0; j < columns; j++){ // iterate through column
            doubleArray[i][j] = Double.parseDouble(stringArray[i][j]); // cast each string value to 
        }
    }
    return doubleArray;
}
```

It was actually an extremely easy fix. It was simply my fundamental misunderstanding of objects. I created a method that returned a `double` array instead.

Comment: Gotta wait two more days =).

Comment: Thanks! Will be aware of this.

Comment: It's true, remember that when you return that array, wherever receives it can make changes to it from outside the class that "owns" it (except reassignment of the entire array). Not necessarily a bad thing but it's an extremely common thing to miss.

Comment: That works too. Just be careful with regards to exposing your entire array to other parts of your program; if you accidently cause some value to be changed in the array unexpectedly, that might cause you some headaches. (Sorry deleted original comment by accident. Adding back).

Comment: @Teeg @Radiodef Are you two suggesting that I not set it as `public` and set it something else?

Comment: @theGreenCabbage No, keep the method public. In your scenario, you said that `JHeatChart` requires a 2d double array, and since you're encapsulating that array in a class, you ultimately need to do something like what you've show here, or something like Radiodef's answer. However, for all other situations in your application, if you need to get a specific value at a particular row and column index, it is recommended to do something like my answer, rather than pass around a reference to the actual 2d array itself, to avoid accidentally changing some value in the array unexpectedly. Make sense?

Comment: @theGreenCabbage Ultimately, our suggestion is merely a **general** word of caution. It is possible you may not have encountered this problem anyways, but when exposing a dependent field, such as this 2d array, the danger exists that some part of your (or **a**) program might change some value unexpectedly, without the knowledge of the encapsulating object. This, again I use the word *in general*, can cause some headaches, and would be considered a bad practice if it were done.

Answer (score 2):

`timeValueArray.doubleArray` will access the array if the main method is in the same package as StoreArray. Otherwise you have to make a method that returns the array. (These are sometimes called "getters".)

```
public Double[][] getDoubleArray() {
    return doubleArray;
}
```

Then call it like `Double[][] yourReturnedArray = timeValueArray.getDoubleArray();`.

Multidimensional arrays are just an array of arrays. So to access elements in the array, first you need to enter the index of the array within the array:

```
timeValueArray[0]
```

Will access the zeroth `Double[]` array. (The "first" index but since arrays typically start with 0 the "first" is called the zeroth and the first is actually the "second".)

Now you can call an index on *that* array:

```
timeValueArray[0][0] = 1.0;

zeroth array --^  ^-- zeroth element in that array
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot implement operators such as the array access operators(the `[ ]`) in java, so you can't quite do exactly what you're thinking.

However, I think a simple solution would be to create a method in your class which essentially behaves the same way, something that will give you the desired value at the specified row and column. Something like this:

```
public Double get(int rowIndex, int columnIndex){
    return doubleArray[rowIndex][columnIndex]
}
```

Comment: I think the OP's clarification means they just wanted to do something like `new SomeClass(doubleArray)` and were maybe trying to pass as `new SomeClass(doubleArray[][])`.

Comment: @Radiodef Yeah, I think I misunderstood originally. Since they said `JHeatChart` requires a double array, this means they need to access their 2d double array, not individual elements. I'll leave this here regardless incase it is of any help to the OP.